# Unable to create new record in access 2007 split form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've been developing an access 2007 database, and have run into a problem adding new records via a split view form.

To prevent accidental deletion on fields, I've added a lock button on each form (2nd from right in image below). The user toggles this button to switch between edit mode and read only mode. By default the form is in read only mode.

[image: Split Form]

This VBA code on the button click event toggles the following properties `AllowEdits`, `AllowAdditions`, `AllowDeletions`, and also toggles the enabled state of the 'Delete Record' and 'Add Record' buttons, using the following code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ReadOnly (True)
End Sub

Private Sub btnLock_Click()
    If lblEditMode.Caption = "Edit Mode" Then
        ReadOnly (True)
    Else
        ReadOnly (False)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ReadOnly(value As Boolean)
    Dim enableState As Boolean
    enableState = Not value
    If Dirty Then Dirty = False
    AllowEdits = enableState
    AllowAdditions = enableState
    AllowDeletions = enableState
    BtnNew.Enabled = enableState
    BtnDelete.Enabled = enableState
    If enableState = False Then
        lblEditMode.Caption = ""
    Else
        lblEditMode.Caption = "Edit Mode"
    End If
End Function
```

Originally, I used custom navigation buttons at the bottom of the form, but then removed these in favour of using a split form.

Now all I can do on my form is edit or delete records. I can't add a new record.

I've gone through the all the properties I can think of using design view, but haven't found anything that might be causing this. Any ideas what might be causing this?

I've modified a number of forms to use a split view, and they all now suffer with the same problem.

The 'Add New' button (which uses standard macros) generates the message 'You can't go to the specified record'. The datasheet part of the form doesn't show an insertable line at the bottom. Furthermore, the 'Add' button on the Home ribbon enables and disables as the state of `AllowAdditions` is toggled.

Edit: Changing the form from a split form back to a single form allows me to add new records. But as soon as I change the form back to a split form again, I lose the ability to add new records.

Comment: Is the second form a subform? Could you give us details about the underlying table/query?!

Comment: No, it's a split form, i.e. same data represented in the top and bottom of the form. The datagrid at the bottom shows many records, but the main part of the form (top) shows the record selected in the datagrid. There is nothing unusual with the data. It's just a series of various types of field (string, long, date, indexed auto incrementing PK ID field) with a number of lookup tables (depicted by the combo boxes).

Comment: Do you have this available anywhere online as a sample/test database that could be downloaded? It does look to me like it could possibly be an Access bug. I would suggest you also post at UtterAccess. There's several MVP's there that might take an interest in looking into this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks HK1. I'm not sure if I can put it online (at least not in its current form). I'm not familiar with UtterAccess TBH, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply. But this may help others. 
I think you placed all the controls in Form Header. Please place all the controls in Detail section and give a try..Hope this solve the problem.